# Adding documents via batch write vs manually adding from console (possible firestore bug?)

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I created a CSV to Firestore exporter and have every fields the exact same as required by my app to read the data and populate it on a recycler.

After exporting successfully, and the fields look the same to me, the entries does not appear on the recycler.

I used batch write and the entries appear all nice and well on console.

However, if I add 1 entry manually onto the same collection, that entry will appear immediately on the recycler!

Would this be a Firestore bug? Have anyone encountered this before?

Edit - the batch write codes:

```
  try { 
        InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedfile);

        final CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String [] nextLine;
        String column1 ="", column2="", column3="", column4 = "";
        Integer count=0;


        FirebaseFirestore fs =  FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        FirebaseFirestoreSettings settings = new FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
                .setTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled(true)
                .build();
        fs.setFirestoreSettings(settings);

        WriteBatch batch = fs.batch();

        while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
            if (count > 0) {

                DocumentReference productList = fs
                        .collection("ProductList")
                        .document("VendorA")
                        .collection("Items")
                        .document(nextLine[0]);

                Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
                data.put(column1, nextLine[0]);
                data.put(column2, nextLine[1]);
                data.put(column3, nextLine[2]);
                data.put(column4, nextLine[3]);

                batch.set(productList, data);
                count++;
            } else {
                //first line of CSV file are the headers
                column1 = nextLine[0];
                column2 = nextLine[1];
                column3 = nextLine[2];
                column4 = nextLine[3];
                count++;
            }
        }

        batch.commit().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                mStatusUpdate.setText(getString(R.string.statusupdate, reader.getLinesRead() - 1));
                mVendorName.setText("");
            }
        });
        reader.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Edit #2:
I think I found the issue. Look at the attached picture. I just reported this to Firebase Support as well.

I added another same field with "Name" from the Firebase Console.

I'm not sure why Firestore is allowing a duplicate field here. They look exactly the same, I can't find any typo on both the fields.

[image: screenshot]
Screen shot here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQ3xS.jpg

After I added the duplicate "Name", my app works fine!

Answer (score 0):

This is the normal behaviour. When you are saying that `will appear immediately`, it means that you already have added a listener on that collection reference and start listening for changes. Cloud Firestore is a realitime database so when you are using a listener, every CRUD operation that you doind in your database will be visibile in your RecyclerView.

But note, this is not a bug, is the most important features of Cloud Firestore.

Comment: Hey Alex. I understand, but when I add data with batch write, and after completion, closing and re-opening the app, the data still does not appear on recyclerview.

Comment: It means that you have something wrong in your code. Please add your code.